# Add social links & Phone to NavWalker Wordpress Menu

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've successfully added a bootstrap menu to Wordpress.  My navbar has a slight difference than the basic bootstrap navbar in that I have a large image, phone number, and facebook link above the navigation links.

I am using navwalker plugin that allows me to add/edit links using the normal Wordpress menu editor.

I need to add the code below to the navwalker system so it shows up on my page. I don't need to edit this code in the editor.

Current NavBar:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/logolarge.png" class="center-block img-responsive" alt="Cocke Chiropractic Clinic"/>                
        </div>
        <?php
            wp_nav_menu( array(
                'menu'              => 'primary',
                'theme_location'    => 'primary',
                'depth'             => 2,
                'container'         => 'div',
                'container_class'   => 'navbar-collapse collapse',
                'container_id'      => 'navigation',
                'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav navLarge',
                'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
                'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
            );
        ?>      
    </div>
</div>
```

Outside of:

```
<div class="contact hidden-xs">
        <span>Call Now! <a href="tel:2058708787">(205) 870-8787</a></span>
        <br />
        <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/fbsmall.png" class="social img-responsive pull-right" /></a>
    </div>
```

The code below is inserted into the wp_nav_menu navwalker above.  I need the .contact div to show up in the navwalker menu as well.  How do I do that?

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <div class="contact hidden-xs">
        <span>Call Now! <a href="tel:2058708787">(205) 870-8787</a></span>
        <br />
        <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/fbsmall.png" class="social img-responsive pull-right" /></a>
    </div>                
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navLarge" id="navigation">
        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li class="divider-vertical-second-menu class=hidden-xs"></li>
        <li><a href="">About</a></li>
        <li class="divider-vertical-second-menu class=hidden-xs"></li>
        <li><a href="">Service/Treatments</a></li>
        <li class="divider-vertical-second-menu class=hidden-xs"></li>
        <li><a href="">FAQ</a></li>
        <li class="divider-vertical-second-menu class=hidden-xs"></li>
        <li><a href="">New Patient</a></li>
        <li class="divider-vertical-second-menu class=hidden-xs"></li>
        <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
        <li class="hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg"><a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/fbsmall.png" class="img-responsive" /></a></li>
    </ul>
```

What I'm looking for:
[image]

What I currently have:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this my moving my code Nav Walker call:

```
            <div class="contact hidden-xs">
                <span>Call Now! <a href="tel:2058708787">(205) 870-8787</a></span>
                <br />
                <a href="https://www.facebook.com/Cocke-Chiropractic-Clinic-122171807867845/?fref=ts" target="_blank"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/fbsmall.png" class="social img-responsive pull-right" /></a>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can edit `WP-Bootstrap-Navwalker.php`

OR

use like this

```
<ul class="navbar-nav nav-flex-icons">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link p-1" href="tel:02332224491"><i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i>Call me</a>
                </li></ul>
```